# Regular Expression - exclude part of string

Tags: regex

This is a follow-up to a [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346521/assistance-with-a-regular-expression). I have a string "Test 999-99-9", how would I match on everything except the last -9 part? Keep in mind, the last -9 may or may not be there, but if it is, I want to ignore it and match on the rest of the string. Any suggestions?

Alternatively, if it ignored the entire 999-99-9 or 999-99 part, and just returned the "Test" part, that would be fine, too. It seems like that may be easier to do. I basically want to take the following expression and invert it to return the other half of the string: (\d{3}-\d{2}|\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{1})$

Comment: please post some possible inputs and the respective desired outputs

Comment: Well, like I explained above, if the input is either "Test 999-99" or "Test 999-99-9", I just want it to output "Test 999-99" (ignore the last -9 if it is present). Or, as I explained in the 2nd paragraph, if it just returned "Test", that would be fine too (I can isolate the 999-99 pattern using a different expression I already wrote). Keep in mind, the character part of the string could be more than one word, if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RegEx to ignore 999-99-9 and just return "Test" part:

```
^([\w ]+) [\d]{3}-[\d]{2}-?[\d]?$
```

OCR Software supports groups:

http://www.laserfiche.com/NewsPortal/Article/2012/05/21/tech-tip-pattern-matching-with-regular-expressions

> Note: The parentheses determine which information is extracted from
>   the text. The other characters determine the pattern that will be
>   looked for. For example, \d\d\d-\d\d-(\d\d\d\d) will find the social
>   security number and return the last four digits of it.

Comment: I am testing this at http://regexpal.com/ and it seems to return the entire string, not just the first part.

Comment: It matches the whole string, but returns just the "Test" part as group 1, which you can access using $1 with most regex systems

Comment: I guess I'm not familiar with groups, or how to access them. Do I just tack the $1 onto the end of the expression? Also, the "Test" part may be multiple words; I'm not sure if this will match if multiple words. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: This is for Laserfiche Quick Fields (http://www.laserfiche.com/en-us/products/quick-fields) zone OCR scanning software. You can inject regex when you map the OCR zone to the metadata field, so the regex basically has to be stand-alone. And I'm not sure what language it would be. Basically when it reads a string, I want it to split it based on this pattern and store the strings in different metadata fields.

Comment: @tjc59 Ok, updated my answer to match multiple words.  It depends on which language you are using as to how to display match groups.

Comment: Try replacing it in the OCR software with something and it should only replace "Test"

Comment: I'm not sure what you meant by that last comment. Basically this my mapping in the software: %(TokenName#<regex goes here>#). My regex has to go between the <>, and it needs to return just the left side of the string (exclude the number pattern), and do it all inline.

Comment: @tjc59 No need to worry about groups. You can use it as is and it should return "Test" or equivalent.

Comment: Ok, I'll go test this out, but like I said above, when I tested it at regexpal.com it returned the entire string and didn't isolate anything.

Comment: Note that if you use the 'g' option then match won't return the groups: http://javular.com/regex/3. Without the 'g' option, it looks fine: http://javular.com/regex/2.

Answer (score 0):

`^(Test \d{3}-\d{2})(-\d{1})?$` will return everything except the last "-9" from your example, whether the "-9" is present or not.

Comment: This seems to return everything, no matter what, when I test it. Also, the word "Test" is not static; it could be a whole series of different words. I'm basically trying to do an inverse match on everything that doesn't match the 999-99 or 999-99-9 pattern.

Comment: This is horrible RegEx.  You are literally matching the word "Test" and you are matching the last 9, but treating it as a second group.